# Activity tab - IMPACT showing ~1000k

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, people-reached

[image]

Why doesn't it show "~1m" instead? What are the rules of deciding when to switch to "m"?

I'm asking because I saw many profiles that has "~X.Ym" and I'm curious to know when do we display what.

Comment: I'd venture a guess that it rounded it up from something between 999,500 and 999,999 and the system doesn't handle that particular case properly.

Comment: Well seems like you didn't reached SO servers yet :) Maybe you do it with this question on meta and it gets changed to `~1m`

Comment: Blurgh, I recently reworked all that code to support localization (for pt.SO mostly at the moment, though ja & ru are in the works).  I probably introduced this, digging.

Comment: It now says ~1.0M when I look

Comment: Was this just a "hey everybody, look at my wicked stats!" type of post? ;P

Comment: @thissuitisblacknot no (condensing the fact that it is not that wicked), it's more like "hey everybody, look at this bug"

Comment: Someone on MSE already beat you to this, but no answers though: [Impact stat says I have reached a thousand thousand people](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256838/impact-stat-says-i-have-reached-a-thousand-thousand-people)

Comment: @TravisJ now I can die in peace ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Blurgh, what an irritating edge case.

This should be fixed as of the latest build, we're now explicitly rounding in the last digit for those style numbers.  Previously we were relying on `string.Format`'s rounding behavior... which obviously had some issues.