# Impact Estimate on user profile shows decreased number

Tags: support, people-reached

Yesterday, it was showing `~1.1m` and now its updated to `~1.0m`, How's that possible? Is there an issue with estimate calculation?

Comment: A post was removed or downvoted into oblivion?

Comment: @Docteur, No post was either removed or downvote

Comment: @Satpal How do you know? It might be an old question that you posted an answer to.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, Correct me, that will still be displayed in recently deleted question/answers queue

Comment: mine changed too from 2.9m to 2.8m

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, impact *can* go down if a post stops being eligible because it's deleted, or because it's been downvoted or unupvoted or unaccepted, or because sufficiently many other answers have been upvoted more. See [Servy's answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257318/can-impact-go-down/257319#257319) for more details.

Second, there was a rounding bug where numbers were rounded up instead of rounded to nearest, which was [fixed yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295282/activity-tab-impact-showing-1000k). This is probably what you saw: your impact number must be between 1.0m and 1.05m, and was previously incorrectly rounded to 1.1m and is now correctly 1.0m. This bug did not affect the calculation of the number, only the way it was displayed.

Comment: I have to say that I like the idea that downvoting revises downwards the reach estimate. Almost as if to say, "Hm... Maybe people weren't really paying that much attention after all..."