# Rounding / truncation on vote counts has changed, was this intended?

Tags: discussion, top-users

It seems the rounding / truncation for vote counts has changed.  It used to be rounding, e.g. 17920 -> 18k.  But now it truncates that is 17920 -> 17k.

Not that this is a bug, but was this intended?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has [now been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256838/impact-stat-says-i-have-reached-a-thousand-thousand-people/257310?noredirect=1#comment839631_257310):

> should be properly rounding to nearest now, not just flooring it.

---

*Original post*:

Yes, this changed, but is being reviewed as perhaps unintentional.

A [bug in the user impact number display](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295282/activity-tab-impact-showing-1000k) was fixed, but as a side-effect now **all** numbers are rounded down, including user reputation and per-badge votes.

When people pointed this out, [the developer responded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256838/impact-stat-says-i-have-reached-a-thousand-thousand-people/257310?noredirect=1#comment839254_257310) to say they'll review this change:

> Yeaaaah, sort of by design... But I don't particularly like it. Will dig in yet more tomorrow, i18n is just a pain around numbers in general.

Comment: @false: I saw the change yesterday. I was doing a double take as I was sure I was further away from overtaking CMS on the overall user list than the new display implied; it was as if they had dropped 1000 points..

Comment: I would be worried to if my rep was 365K.... ;)

Comment: @rene: not *worried*. But when you've been using the site as often as I have sudden changes like these stand out.

Comment: Today I learned what [i18n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) means...

Answer (score 0):

Rounding is back! Relief!

Comment: But your name is false… so it's not back? I'm so confused.

Comment: @bjb568: Did you pronounce my name correctly?

Comment: I don't even know!

Comment: Ha! I knew it!!